# Objective c constantly checking variable values

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I need to have a loop that can constantly check for this variable:

```
NSString *charlieSoundVolume;
charlieSoundVolume = [charlieSoundLevel stringValue];
```

This variable will change by an interface builder patch. I was thinking of doing this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  while(1) {
    float floatValue;
    floatValue = 0.0001;
    NSString *charlieSoundVolume;
        charlieSoundVolume = [charlieSoundLevel stringValue];
    if(charlieSoundVolume >= floatValue){
         (do something)
        }


}

}
```

But this will freeze the rest of the application. What is another way of doing this?

Thanks,
Elijah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/fire).

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
 float floatValue = 0.0001;
 NSString *charlieSoundVolume = [charlieSoundLevel stringValue];
 if (charlieSoundVolume >= floatValue) {
  // do something
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks!! I get this error though: invalid operands to binary >=

Comment: @Elijah: That's the same code from your question, except put into a timer block and with the definitions and assignments on the same line. You'd have gotten the same error with the code you posted, I believe.

Comment: Yes, I know. But what's the fix for this problem?

Comment: Its impossible to tell from what you have posted so far. If you get that error, then run the app in Debug mode (with "Stop on Objective-C Exceptions") enabled, and check which line is causing it.

Comment: if (charlieSoundVolume >= floatValue) {
This is the line

Comment: Here's a hint: Look at the types of the variables.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be polling for changes to a text field like this. Instead, have whatever sets the value of the text field also notify your other code that a property it cares about has changed.